# Run Python Code on CentOS without GUI in background

Tags: python, centos, putty

I have a python script and I would like to execute it on my server with CentOS, this OS doesnt have a GUI and I'm connecting to it via `putty` But I would like to execute this code in Putty and be able to leave code running even if I log-out from Putty, Is there a way to do it please?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest screen https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/

You can install this with `yum install screen`

To start a screen session you can simple run `screen` or `screen -S mysession`

Once attached you can run any command and detach from the screen session and the command will continue to run in the background.

To detach from the screen session (leave everything running and return to the original shell) you can press `ctrl + a and d`

Once detached from the screen session you can disconnect from ssh. When you log back in you can list all screen sessions with `screen -ls` and reattach to the session with `screen -r`

Screen is pretty powerful and handy and I would suggest checking out the man page for more in depth usage.

Answer (score 0):

In contrast to `screen`, there is also [`tmux`](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki) (Terminal Multiplexer).

It allows you to create detachable sessions, with multiple windows and panels.
When you need to leave the computer, you can detach and close the SSH session, then when you need to return you can re-connect and attach to the tmux session as you left it before.

Fundamental controls are (where `^B` is <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>):

- `tmux new` - Create a new session
- `^B`, `D` - Detach from a session
- `tmux attach` - Attach to the last session
- `exit` - Exit the shell to terminate the tmux session (or panel / window)

More advanced controls:

- `^B`, `%` - Split a window vertically
- `^B`, `"` - Split a window horizontally
- `^B`, `c` - Create a new window
- `^B`, `n` - Go to the next window
- `^B`, `p` - Go to the previous window

[image: tmux example]

Answer (score 0):

The most minimal way to do this is probably `nohup` – it will protect the program started by it from hangup messages and thus allow it to keep running when you log out. Any output produced from the program will be redirected into a file. This works fine for programs that only produce simple output. If there is some kind of interactive interface (e.g. curses) things will get more complex and you will be better off with the previous answers. But for simple situations `nohup` is what I recommend.

usage:

```
nohup yourcommand
```

see `man nohup` for details